# How to remove nodes from XML if attribute matches value in another file?

Tags: xml, xslt

Supposing I have an xml file like the one below:

```
<client name="Mary" id="123"/>
<client name="Anthony" id="456"/>
<client name="Theo" id="789"/>
```

I want to delete all nodes that have id equal to one of the values from another file. This other file is a plain-text file, but can be changed to xml if it makes the solution easier.

```
List_Of_Ids.txt:
123
789
```

I need the final result to be:

```
<client name="Anthony" id="456"/>
```

Consider also that the list of clients xml and the list of ids both contain hundreds of records.

I want to do something like the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
<xsl:param name="ids-to-delete" select="123, 789"/>
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="client[id = $ids-to-delete]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But instead of listing all ids to delete, I want them to be read from List_Of_Ids.txt.

Could a kind soul help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<xsl:param name="ids-to-delete" select="unparsed-text-lines('List_Of_Ids.txt')"/>`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-unparsed-text-lines.